# Axios request sent twice when using React Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-saga

I am trying to send a GET request using axios and React Saga.
The request fired twice

This is my component file where I call the getBusinessHoursList action:

```
import { getBusinessHoursList } from "../../../../redux/actions";
...
...
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getBusinessHoursList(this.state.id);  
 }
...
...
const mapStateToProps = ({ settings }) => {
    return {
        settings
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {
        getBusinessHoursList,
    }
  )(injectIntl(BusinessHours));
```

This is my service file where I use axios to get my business hours list:
setting-service.js:

```
import axios from '../util/api';
import { configureStore } from '../redux/store';
export const settingsService = 
{
  getBusinessHours,
};

function getBusinessHours() {
  const store = configureStore({});
  const user = JSON.parse(store.getState().authUser.user)
  return axios.get("business/" + user.business.id + "/businesshours")
  .then(response => {
      return response.data.data
  }).catch(error => {
      return error.response.data
  })
}
```

This is actions file where I define the actions
actions.js:

```
import {
    CHANGE_LOCALE, 
    SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS_FAIL,
    SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS_SUCCESS,
    SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS,
} from '../actions';

export const getBusinessHoursList = (data) => ({
    type: SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS,
    payload: data
});

export const getBusinessHoursSuccess = (items) => ({
    type: SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS_SUCCESS,
    payload: items
});

export const getBusinessHoursFail = (error) => ({
    type: SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS_FAIL,
    payload: error
});
```

reducer.js

```
import {
    CHANGE_LOCALE,
    SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS,
    SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS_FAIL,
    SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS_SUCCESS
} from '../actions';

const INIT_STATE = {
    errors: '',
    loadingBH: false,
    businessHoursItems: null
};

export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS:
            return { ...state, loadingBH: false };

        case SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loadingBH: true, businessHoursItems: action.payload};

        case SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS_FAIL:
            return { ...state, loadingBH: true, errors: action.payload };

        default: return { ...state };
    }
}
```

saga.js:

```
import { all, call, fork, put, takeEvery, takeLatest, take } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { getDateWithFormat } from "../../helpers/Utils";
import { settingsService } from '../../services/settings-service'

import {
  SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS,
  SETTING_UPDATE_BUSINESS_HOURS,
} from "../actions";

import axios from "../../util/api";

import { NotificationManager } from "../../components/common/react-notifications";

import {
  getBusinessHoursSuccess,
  getBusinessHoursFail,
} from "./actions";



const getServiceListRequest = async () =>
await settingsService.getBusinessHours()
.then(authUser => authUser)
.catch(error => error);

function* getBusinessHours() {
  console.log('test')
  try {
    const response = yield call(getServiceListRequest);
    yield put(getBusinessHoursSuccess(response));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(getBusinessHoursFail(error));
  }
}

export function* watchGetBusinessHours() {
  yield takeLatest(SETTING_GET_BUSINESS_HOURS, getBusinessHours);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(watchGetBusinessHours), 
  ]);
}
```

Global sagas file : sagas.js:

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import authSagas from './auth/saga';
import settingsSagas from './settings/saga';

export default function* rootSaga(getState) {
  yield all([
    authSagas(),
    settingsSagas(),
  ]);
}
```

The request fired successfully and I get Business hours list but the request fired twice
I tried to use takeLatest in place of takeEvery

This is the network tab
[image]

Comment: in your network tab can you check whether the first call RequestMethod: Options and second is RequestMethod:Get

Comment: If you can check above then if thats the case then its because of preflighted requests. let me know if the above comment is the problem then will add more resources or need to check it further

Comment: @DILEEP THOMAS No it send 4 requests 2 OPTIONS and 2 GET

Comment: @ Selmi in the question it is mentioned as twice, so basically two times api call is happening and two times options call is happening am i correct

Comment: I dont have fair knowledge in redux saga, but as a general thought process in componentDidMount have called the method for api call that will call the actions and it will be passed to the reducers thats the actual work flow, but why do you need saga.js and you have called the method getBusinessHours again, is that the issue ?

Comment: instead of total 4, 2 Options and 2 Actual api if it is total is 2 and one is options and one is get then its fine because before sending the actual api preflight request will be send thats how it works. I see this saga.js calls the method again thats y you are getting total 4 can you check that one and let me know

Comment: @ Selmi, okay no issues what was the problem

Comment: @ Selmi kindly update the answer so it will be helpful for others, if it was not related to any of the comments

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS sorry I don't have an answer yet

Comment: I think you have removed the comment, as referring to the comment I was telling